# Arriving at a Schengen country with a Schengen visa

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas, spain, filipino-citizens, uk-residents

I am planning to travel to Spain with my boyfriend’s family (British citizens) in about June, however I have a Filipino passport with a UK indefinite leave to remain visa so I need to get a Schengen visa to enter.

I am aware that when you arrive back in the UK you are subject to question at border control, but I am wondering whether this is the same when arriving at border control in Spain with a Schengen visa? Am I likely to be pulled aside there to get questioned about my visa which will delay my boyfriend’s family as they will need to wait for me? Or will they just check the Schengen visa and wave me through with the rest of my boyfriend's family?

Anyone who has had experience with a Schengen visa in Spain would also really help!

Comment: To clarify, you have Indefinite Leave to Remain in the UK? What nationality is your boyfriend and his family members?

Comment: yes i have ILR in the Uk, and they are all British.

Comment: They may have more chances of being pulled over than you in June (past Brexit ;)

Comment: what are they likely to ask?

Comment: Where you live, whether you plan to go back there, do you have ties there, like a job or a house.

Comment: yes! i live in the UK with  my mum and i even go to university here. i have lived in the UK for 18 years and i am 19 years old. We just have not been able to afford a full British citizenship.

Answer (score 2):

There will be a check of your visa and passport as you arrive. How long this takes depends on many things -- the length of the waiting lines, the desire of the officer to take a coffee break, your appearance and demeanor. You should be able to answer questions about what you will do in Spain and when/how you will leave confidently and then your passport gets stamped. If you appear nervous, or different from the typical ILR resident, there may be more questions and it takes a few minutes more.

Probably the real difference will not be the length of your interview, it will be the length of the waiting lines at the various gates.

June will presumably be after Brexit, so nobody has any idea which rules apply to your boyfriend. It could happen that you will get through faster ...